# jQuery mobile Trigger create doesn't completely work with element added through DOM

Tags: jquery-mobile

I have to add istantly some items without reload the page. After adding these elements I call

```
$('#one').trigger('create');
```

But not everything changes as it should (screenshot: http://www.ianaz.com/9a7c50414.html )
The background stays grey, the icon at the right is not added and the text becomes link.
It does not transform everything in a list "button". The third component in the screenshot is as should be.
Do I have to call another method?
Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just before you call create,try to call `listview("refresh")` on the list.For eg. if list is the `id` of the listview,following code should be used:

```
$("#list").listview("refresh");
```